# Convert a string to number in php

Tags: php

I have this line of code...

```
$ide=str_replace('idEdu=', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

In which i get a string which is always a number and I want this string to make it integer.

I want to get for example the number 3 for the url which can be like this one ***addCV.php?idEdu=3***

Can you help me please to achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: @Rizier123 what do you mean by saying "cast" , do you have to suggest me something

Comment: Yep I have: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting <- Maybe you even can solve this problem yourself :D

Comment: Why not use `$_GET['idEdu']` rather than trying to extract from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: @MarkBaker cant find a way how i can use the $_GET and i tried once that by not correctly i believe . If you have to suggest me something feel free to do it :)

Comment: put `var_dump($_GET); die();` in your code, and edit your question to show us what is displayed

Comment: @MarkBaker this it the output 0array(0) { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either cast as int or use intval():

```
 $num=(int)$_GET['idEdu'];
```

or

```
 $num=intval($_GET['idEdu']);
```

Casting should be 4 times as fast.

Comment: if a echo num then it displays me 0 as a number

Comment: @niklakis Then tell us what the value of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is

Comment: it is a value from the url of the page that it is always a number and i want to get this number and store it as $ide

Comment: does your url have idedu=number?

Comment: yes for example i can have this one idEdu=4 and I want to get 4. I did that with my code but I want it to be stored as integer in order to use it my database

Comment: Ok, if you are using str_replace($_SERVER...) try put that string inside a trim() before converting it. Btw, it's better if you use $_GET.

Comment: @uraimo how should i use the get methods

Comment: Instead of `str_replace('idEdu=', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` use `$_GET['idEdu']`

Comment: i get this  Notice: Undefined index: idEdu in E:\xampp\htdocs\CVToolGismo\addCV.php on line 272

Comment: are you sure you have ?idEdu=1 in your url? paste it here. Which version of php are you using?

Comment: yes my url is this one addCV.php?idEdu=3 and I want to get number 3 and store it as an integer

Comment: @niklakis php version? Do a a phpinfo()

Comment: Where can i see the php version ? And i think that it i get 0 as the number because when i click on update button on form it redirect my page to addCV.php

Comment: Just to know if you have $_Get support... it's php4+. And when you redirect you have the correct parameter in your url? This is really weird... it looks like you don't get any parameter with the querystring, try running it manually, without the button redirect, just type the address you have added to your question.

Comment: the url in the form is addCV.php and this is the reason why it doesnt keep the number because it redirects it to this url but I cant change that because my code is store in the named file

Comment: Why don't you add an hidden idEdu field in the form?

Comment: i have ...   <input type="hidden" name="idEdu" id="idE" value="<?php echo ($id == 0 ? 0 : $id );?>" style="border: 1px solid #006; color:#F87F25; font: bold 16px Tahoma; border-radius:7px; padding:4px;"/>

Comment: If this is data from an html form, is your submit method a GET or a POST?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
$ide = intval(str_replace('idEdu=', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
```

Comment: If I do what you said it displays me 0 as a number

Comment: @niklakis Then tell us what the value of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is

Comment: it is a value from the url of the page that it is always a number and i want to get this number and store it as $ide

Comment: @niklakis - Show us the output from a `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])`... if the value was a number other than `0` then you'd get that number; if you get `0` then either the number is zero, or it isn't a number

Comment: Exactly. For instance, do a var_dump($ide) without the intval function in front and post the result below in the comments.